# What device to power 4 directional coils to rotate magnetic field

Tags: stepper-motor, driver, electromagnetic, electromagnet

I am trying to make a solid state device that creates a magnetic field applied on an sample that can control the field direction and strength.

My current design uses a 8 coil stepper stator that has been rewired so that the opposite pole coils are connected and aligned such that when current flows through them, the field they generate sums. Then I can independently control the current through each pair of coils. (i.e. there are 4 circuits with two coils aligned opposite each other, aligned N, NW, W, SW). The external sample is placed inside the stator.

My issue is that to rotate the field in this solid state device, I need a controller (I'm using an arduino) to make each direction pair vary sinusoidally with an input angle from a potentiometer, which cannot output high current (I want max 2A), so I am outputting to 2 L298N driver circuits, where each driver controls the direction (+ or -) and magnitude (following sinusoid) of 2 directional coil pairs (there are 2 motor controls that I am using). This has mostly worked, but I have found out (thanks EE stack exchange, and my measurements being weird) that the L298N will not take low input voltages (aka there is a threshold) and has a minimum output voltage. It also does not create a current source.

By cutting off low voltages, the accuracy of the rotation is compromised and the summed magnitude is not constant while changing angle, this is important.

Is there a better device (than the L298N) that I can use for this purpose?
In summary:

- produces positive and negative current correspondent to a input signal voltage from a controller
- Needs to output magnitude of 0 to low to high current (max of 2A), but I don't care about voltage, (my coils have resistances of 3 ohms)
- IDEALLY, are current controlled, but otherwise I could use a current sensor and my controller to keep it stable

Thanks!

Comment: How do you intend to send the sinusoidal control signal from the Arduino? What is the maximum frequency of the sine wave?

Comment: I am not outputting a sine function with time. I need the arduino to compute the sine of an analog input, and this result is outputted to the driver circuit and then to the coils. For example, If my angle is set to 90deg (with 0 at north and so 90 = W) (analog input of 258/1.24V), then the horizontal coils will have Vs cos(90 - 90) = Vs V and Vs cos(90) = Vs vertical, Vs cos(90- 45) = Vs 1/sqrt(2) NW, and Vs cos(90 + 45) = - Vs 1/sqrt(2) NE .

Comment: _"I am not outputting a sine function with time."_ - if you are changing it then you are outputting some function with time, but I will presume you don't care how slowly it responds (within reason). This is important because the Arduino's 'analog' output is actually 490Hz PWM. To produce a smooth DC voltage it needs to be low pass filtered, which slows the response. If you don't mind it taking a second or so to reach the set value then plenty of filtering can be applied to reduce PWM ripple.

Comment: You are right, I don't mind taking the time for it to settle. Do you think that the L298 would have reached the correct DC voltage if I gave it the time to settle if I put an enabler voltage of 0.2V, for example?

Comment: What is the inductance of the electromagnets? If a bit of current ripple is no problem, you can use a simple PWM and count on the inductance to smooth the current. This will be efficient. If you want almost perfectly smooth current then you could use class D amps or other switching driver with an output filter. If you want perfectly smooth current then you need a linear control scheme. This should be decided depending on the needs of your physics experiment...